# Add Progressbar over main layout

Tags: android, user-interface, layout, progress-bar

I would like to add to my main layout a progressbar with visibility = GONE at the beginning.

After a user click a serverrequest will be sent and handle in asynctask. In that time, progressbar should be visible and staying over my main layout.

I tried to do this using merge-layout.

The main problem is, that it's still possible to edit ui-elements and click the buttons. Is it possible to prevent this behaviour?

Maybe there are some layout propertiers i don't know about?

**progressbar.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:id="@+id/waiting_dialog"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/transparent_grey">  
    <ProgressBar 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**main_layout.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/ticket_reg_linear_inner" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:background="@drawable/bg_main" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" 
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" 
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/ticket_reg_phone_edit"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                android:text="@string/text_491" 
                android:maxLines="1" android:singleLine="true" android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ticket_reg_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"         
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
                android:text="@string/text_activate"/>              
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <include layout="@layout/waiting_dialog"/>  
</merge>
```

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of thing it would be better to create a [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) that will mask your Activity. You create it in `onCreateDialog()` and show it with `showDialog()` before your start the task, and dismiss it once the task completes with `dismissDialog()` in `onPostExecute()` of AsyncTask.

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
progressDialog.setTitle("Loading");
progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
```

Comment: I know this. However i wanted to add progressbar over layout. It looks nicer and in my opinion easier to handle for device rotations, i just need to change visibility of progressbar.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a progress bar into the main xml file where you need it and in the main class file you can set the progressbar's to Visibility as you desire.To first make the progressbar invisible, in the oncreate method set the progressbar property like this

```
progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.myprogressBar);
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Then you can make the progress bar visible inside the onClickListener or whereever you want the progressbar to be visible,

```
progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
progressbar.setProgress(0);
```

And finally you can set the visibility to `View.GONE` on completion of the process.

Answer (score 0):

Another option will be using a progressDialog...

```
private ProgressDialog dialog;


dialog = new ProgressDialog(MyApp.this);
dialog.setTitle("this is my ProgressBar");
dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
dialog.setCancelable(true);
dialog.show();
```